# JPA Persistence: Automatical remove of not existing referenced entity from list

Tags: java, entity-framework, jpa, persistence

I like to remove an entity, which will be referenced by another entity.
Here my test:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Teacher")
public class Teacher extends Employee{

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Teacher(){
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private List<SchoolSubject> schoolSubjects;
}



@javax.persistence.Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("SchoolSubject")
public class SchoolSubject implements Resource{

    @Id
    private String name;        // Name of the schoolsubject has to be unique

    @Override
    public Long getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public SchoolSubject(){}

    public SchoolSubject(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

So I tried to remove all SchoolSubjects:

```
q = em.createQuery("select ss from SchoolSubject ss");
List<SchoolSubject> subjects = q.getResultList();
for(SchoolSubject subject:subjects)
{
      em.getTransaction().begin();
      em.remove(subject);
      em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

So I know this action will not work because the teacher references to SchoolSubjects. 
- I like to "remove" SchoolSubject and also the SchoolSubject within Teacher's list.

For example:
1. Remove of SchoolSubject
2. Teacher searches for this "SchoolSubject", if it can not be found then remove SchoolSubject automatically from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround is to use a ManyToMany relationship.
So, I iterate over the teachers within the SchoolSubject and remove for each teacher this subject.
After this step I remove this teacher from the list within the SchoolSubject.